# Xcode 6 is telling me that UIViewController doesn't have a member named reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller that is a `UICollectionViewController`, `UICollectionViewDataSource`, and `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

After updating Xcode recently, I'm now getting the following error:

> '(UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'reloadData'

on the following code (`-didCompleteForecast:` is a callback method):

```
func didCompleteForecast() {
    //stuff
    println("got the data back")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

According to Apple's own documentation, `-reloadData:` should be available.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: The error says nothing about `UIViewController` not having the member named `reloadData()` it says `UICollectionView` doesn't have the member. You title was very misleading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's because self.colectionView is optional type (UICollectionView?) so you have to unwrap it:

```
self.collectionView!.reloadData()
```

Comment: Or more safely `self.collectionView?.reloadData()`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this sort of error if you are dealing with a standard `UIViewController`, to which you've added a collection view, but neglected to define an outlet/property called `collectionView`.

In that situation, the `collectionView` reference in `didCompleteForecast` will end up matching against the first `UICollectionViewDelegate` method you have implemented in your class (presumably the `numberOfItemsInSection` method, on the basis of your error message).

---

As Aditya correctly pointed out, you'll also get this error with a `UICollectionViewController` if you don't unwrap the optional `collectionView`.